# if wpf client app connect server or server response overtime, click the client ui will crash, how to avoid it?

Tags: wpf, crash, client-server

I create a wpf cient app which sometimes need to connect server to send or requset data. But if connection timeout or server is busy, then I click the wpf client ui in win7, it will crash.
How can do?

Comment: You need to handle exceptions.  Learn about the `try catch` block.

Comment: Not caused with exceptions, just client is waiting for response from server and non responsive.

Comment: That's not what "crash" means.  You need threading or async.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my description. Can u give me some advice on avoid above problem and threading or async?